# XML read children id?

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I just trying to figure out how to read XML in PHP and i have one problem.

My xml file is something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<videos>
    <video id="159">
        <username>Unknown</username>
        <title>Video Title</title>
        <tags>very, good, tags</tags>
        <duration>123</duration>
        <thumbnail>superduperthumbail.com</thumbnail>
    </video>
</videos>
```

how can i get `<video id="159">` ID number?

My php code:

```
foreach($xml->children() as $videos) {
    $id = $videos->nodeValue; //It doesn't work
    echo "Idas: ".$id." </br>";
    $title = $videos->title;
}
```

So the question is how I can get $id (159)? 
EDIT: I am using SimpleXML

Comment: Are you using SimpleXML or DOMDocument?

Comment: If it's SimpleXML - use `$id = $videos['id'];`

Comment: I am using SimpleXML  sorry forgot to mention.
And thank you it solve the problem. (I think i need to sleep if i coudln't handle this one). Thank you again.